# "Is Peter's party on a Sunday?" Why is the indefinite article used?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, proper-nouns

I saw this sentence in a primary school English textbook:

> Is Peter's party on **a** Sunday?

I wondered why they put an "a" before Sunday.  The teacher said it was correct but didn't explain.

Could someone please explain?

Comment: Related: **[Articles with the days of the week: “Is it a Monday today?”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79086/articles-with-the-days-of-the-week-is-it-a-monday-today)**

Answer (score 9):

In the question, the emphasis is on what day of the week the party is.

If the question were,*"Is Peter's party on Sunday?"*, it would imply the coming Sunday. The party is presumably on a later date and the  emphasis of the question is on what day of the week the party is.

Is it  a Sunday, as opposed to any other day?